# Hiding missing values on bar charts in QGIS

Tags: qgis, chart, missing-data, diagram

I'm trying to hide the bars when there are no values available on my bar charts. This, in order to differentiate missing values from values that are existing but are very close to zero or equal to zero. Do you know if there is a way to do this?

Here is an example on the following image, with the orange arrow indicating missing values and the blue one real values.

[image]

Comment: If you choose in the rendering option to have the line color transparent it will change your style but may solve your problem. Then if you have really small values they could be seen but less. You may add a square root transformation on all the data shown... but it will change what your map express.

Comment: Where is the blue one?